# PrintWindow выдает черный\белый снимок с окна браузера в Windows10

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

Получаю список открытых окон через EnumWindows(user32.dll) и делаю их снимки через PrintWindow(user32.dll).
В Windows7 все работает отлично, а вот в Windows10 окно бразуера на скриншоте получается белое (либо черное).
Через BitBlt(gdi32.dll) тоже пробовал - таже ерунда.

окна получаю так:

```
class OpenWindowsGetter
    {
        [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
        static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc enumFunc, int lParam);
        [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
        static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);
        [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
        static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);
        [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
        static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);
        [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
        static extern IntPtr GetShellWindow();
        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        static extern bool IsIconic(IntPtr hwnd);
        [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
        static extern bool EnumDesktopWindows(IntPtr hDesktop, EnumWindowsProc lpfn, int lParam);
        [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
        static extern bool IsWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, int lParam);
            /// <summary>Returns a dictionary that contains the handle and title of all opened windows.</summary>
            /// <returns>A dictionary that contains the handle and title of all opened windows.</returns>
            public static IDictionary<IntPtr, string> GetOpenWindows()
            {
                IntPtr lShellWindow = GetShellWindow();
                Dictionary<IntPtr, string> lWindows = new Dictionary<IntPtr, string>();

                EnumWindows(
                delegate (IntPtr hWnd, int lParam)
                {                    
                    //if (hWnd == lShellWindow) return true;
                    if (!IsWindowVisible(hWnd)) return true;
                    if (IsIconic(hWnd)) return true;
                    if (!IsWindow(hWnd)) return true;

                    int lLength = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
                    if (lLength == 0) return true;

                    StringBuilder lBuilder = new StringBuilder(lLength);
                    GetWindowText(hWnd, lBuilder, lLength + 1);

                    lWindows[hWnd] = lBuilder.ToString();
                    return true;

                }, 0);

                return lWindows;
            }

    }
```

а картинку либо так:

```
public static class PrintWin
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, out Rect lpRect);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool PrintWindow(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hdcBlt, int nFlags);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct Rect
        {
            public int Left, Top, Right, Bottom;
            public Rectangle ToRectangle()
            {
                return new Rectangle(Left, Top, Right - Left, Bottom - Top);
            }
        }

        public static Bitmap WindImage(IntPtr hwnd, out Rect rect)
        {
            GetWindowRect(hwnd, out rect);
            Bitmap image = new Bitmap(rect.Right - rect.Left, rect.Bottom - rect.Top);
            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image))
            {
                var hdcBitmap = graphics.GetHdc();
                PrintWindow(hwnd, hdcBitmap, 0);
                graphics.ReleaseHdc(hdcBitmap);
            }
            return image;
        }
```

либо эдак:

```
public static class PrintWin
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, out RECT lpRect);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool GetWindowInfo(IntPtr hwnd, ref WINDOWINFO pwi);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool PrintWindow(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hdcBlt, int nFlags);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hwnd);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        static extern bool BitBlt(IntPtr hdc, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, IntPtr hdcSrc, int x1, int y1, uint rop);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct RECT
        {
            public int Left, Top, Right, Bottom;
            public Rectangle ToRectangle()
            {
                return new Rectangle(Left, Top, Right - Left, Bottom - Top);
            }
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct WINDOWINFO
        {
            public int cbSize;
            public RECT rcWindow;
            public RECT rcClient;
            public int dwStyle;
            public int dwExStyle;
            public int dwWindowStatus;
            public uint cxWindowBorders;
            public uint cyWindowBorders;
            public IntPtr atomWindowType;
            public int wCreatorVersion;
        }

        const int SRCCOPY = 0xCC0020;

        public static Bitmap WindImage(IntPtr hwnd, out RECT rect)
        {
            GetWindowRect(hwnd, out rect);
            Bitmap image = new Bitmap(rect.Right - rect.Left, rect.Bottom - rect.Top);
            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image))
            {
                var hdcBitmap = graphics.GetHdc();
                //SetWindowLong(hwnd, (int)-16, (uint)0x02000000);
                WINDOWINFO winf = new WINDOWINFO();
                winf.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(winf);
                GetWindowInfo(hwnd, ref winf);
                BitBlt(hdcBitmap, 0, 0, rect.Right - rect.Left, rect.Bottom - rect.Top, GetDC(hwnd), winf.rcClient.Left, winf.rcClient.Top, SRCCOPY);
                graphics.ReleaseHdc(hdcBitmap);
            }
            return image;
        }
```

всем заранее спасибо!

PS:  с BitBlt что то не так делаю кстати, немного съехавшее изображение получается, но с окном браузера все равно не работает.

Comment: Окно какого именно браузера, или любого?

Comment: @aepot, любого.  Во всяком случае опера, яндекс и edge точно.

Comment: У меня все работает. Через PrintWindow получает изображение, если окно браузера не свернуто.